# https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js Label not found error with MS Edge

Tags: google-analytics, microsoft-edge

On 8th March 2017 I started to see js errors coming out of Google analytics  with the error message "Label not found" being caught by my `window.onerror` handler. It seems to only affect the MS Edge browser. Has anyone else seen this problem?

Comment: Hi Robd, is there a page that shows this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this intermittently using a clean install of MS edge using the [stable edge virtual machine (v 14.14393)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) provided by Microsoft.

In the end I upgraded from the legacy ga.js integration method to the universal one using analytics.js as per these instructions:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs

This fixed it, so I believe this was a bug introduced by Google analytics on or around the 8th March, but that only affected old ga.js integration.

Comment: I have the same problem, but cannot remove classic ga.js, which is entirely frustrating. Are you sure there was an update to ga.js? The [changelog](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/changelog) doesn't mention anything

Comment: @theyetiman I'm not sure that there was an update to ga.js, but I'm pretty sure that the changelog isn't up to date - I would have thought they would have changed something in the last 3 years. I imagine this is a refactoring by them which has gone wrong. In any case I can confirm that switching to analytics.js does fix it. No more js errors since I put it live yesterday, and I have stats for Edge browsers again. Are you able to give more details on why you can't remove ga.js?

Comment: yes it's a business requirement to capture specific data only ga.js provides. Until we engineer another solution we must continue with ga.js. My biggest concern is that ga.js is not tracking things properly in Edge.

Comment: Ah OK I see. In my case when I filtered sessions by user agent I saw an almost 100% drop off from the 8th march and a js error for every edge visit more or less, so I don't think ga.js is even loading on edge. Maybe there is somewhere you can raise a bug with GA. [Here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400)?

Comment: A bug report has been logged at Google, stay tuned!

Comment: @OpenSEO Ah great - thanks. Would it be possible to post a link to the issue so we can track progress?

Comment: hi there! Is there a test page that I can look at for this error?

Comment: @Avi I have now upgraded our staging and prod envs to use universal analytics.js which has fixed the problem. I can give you more details on the bug offline if that helps, let me know how to email you. Thanks.

Comment: @theyetiman Do you have a public facing example page where this bug is still occurring?

Comment: @robd please share the details you have with Avi, there is no public tracker for such issues.

Comment: Our users have reported what seems to be the same problem (window.onerror traps an error in ga.js, although the same-origin policy prevents the browser from showing the exact error).  We are no longer able to reproduce this, although it was happening consistently a week ago.  Maybe Google fixed it already?  @theyetiman, is the problem still happening for you?

Comment: @jcalz, robd: yes, we rolled back the change (Friday evening-Saturday afternoon) and are investigating this further.

Comment: @avi I can share the details with you via email if you like. Perhaps best way to get my email is via linkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/rob-d/ or twitter handle @ robd